# Can I both finish restoring a DB backup and query that DB in the same stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

Here's my setup. Once a day, a full backup of my DB is retrieved from the production server and restored onto a local SQL Server instance. Every 15 minutes aftwerwards, a SQL transaction log is retrieved from production and restored locally.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DBNAME] from disk=@path with NORECOVERY, REPLACE)
RESTORE LOG [DBNAME] from disk=@path with NORECOVERY
```

In case of a failure of the production environment, I need to be able to use the local DB instead. This means "finishing up the restore" and changing some configuration values like this :

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DBNAME] with RECOVERY
UPDATE [DBNAME].dbo.[TABLE] SET [COL1] = 1
```

I have put this code in a stored procedure (in another DB on the same SQL Server instance). However, I am unable to execute it as the second line causes an error:

> Database 'DBNAME' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.

I assume this is due to pre-validation by the SQL Server engine (since the DB is not available until the RESTORE query is executed), but I would like to know how to work around it as cleanly as possible. I found a workaround, which I posted as an answer below, but it's definetely not a great way to solve the problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could do the restore in a separate transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to work around this by placing the second statement in an `EXEC`:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DBNAME] with RECOVERY
EXEC('UPDATE [DBNAME].dbo.[TABLE] SET [COL1] = 1')
```

The issue you're likely seeing is that SQL Server wants to *compile* the entire stored procedure before it starts executing. In order to compile the `UPDATE`, it needs to, at the very least, confirm the existence of the table and column(s) involved.

So, put it in an `EXEC` so that it's not compiled until that part of the procedure is reached.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that and it works like a charm. Simple, readable and functionnal.

I'll wait a bit and then accept your answer if there isn't any better one then.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I have found is simple:

1. Create a stored procedure that executes the query on the database.
2. Call this SP in the first stored procedure.

However, I'd like to avoid cluttering up my SQL Server databases with unnecessary stored procedures if at all possible!

Answer (score 0):

If you know roughly long it takes to restore you could put a delay in it maybe?

```
restore database [DBName] with recovery;
Begin 
    waitfor delay '00:01';  --one minute delay 
        update [DBTable] set [Col1]= 1;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that wouldn't work. I should have been more clear, but what I'm encountering is a compilation error... Nothing gets actually executed.